# Would this statement mean 'all' or 'some'?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is

"Steps taken towards equality are, in fact, segregating us further."

Very simple question. Does this sentence mean *All* steps previously taken towards equality are resulting in more segregation, or just that multiple steps have been taken which are currently resulting in increased segregation? Basically, is it all steps which have been taken, or just more than one steps.

Comment: I would say "some", if only because it would be impossible to even enumerate "all" of the steps that have been taken "towards equality".  However, the implication is that some relatively major "pro-equality" steps have been counter-productive.

Comment: This sentence certainly means _some_, and it may be intended or interpreted as _all_; but it doesn't **mean** _all_. Pragmatics in context determines.

Comment: By implication, the sentence is referring to the latest steps - "segregating us further" indicates an ongoing concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps taken towards equality are, in fact, segregating us further.**

The sentence doesn't explicitly say, but it can be inferred that **Steps** is referring to all the steps as a whole. It doesn't mean some steps and it doesn't mean all steps. It means that the general trend of the steps leads in the segregating direction.

One good analogy is electrical current. Not all particles move in the direction of the current, but rather, they move in all directions, with a trend towards one direction.

Comment: You can't herd people like you can herd electrons.

Comment: @HotLicks The point is the trend.

Comment: Even if the trend is negative, some steps taken may not contribute to that trend, but may have a net positive effect.

Comment: @HotLicks Correct. But the trend is still present. Trend doesn't mean all the steps move in the negative direction, but rather the **net effect** is negative for **all** steps combined.

Comment: Actually, no.  The statement does not imply that the trend is negative, but only that some unspecified set of "steps" have a net negative effect.

Comment: @HotLicks It implies both ways; I just inferred it the way I did. With more context, we can reveal who guessed correctly about what is being implied.

Comment: There is no context. This is the resolution to a debate...

Comment: given that this is the case, does this refer to trends?

Comment: @DiamondLouisXIV I need more information on the debate (initial prompt, argument for this side) to know.

Comment: This is the only possible context

Comment: I have come to understand that in the U.S. Equality for the most part has been achieved for quite some time. However it stands to reason that the methods put in place to level the playing field so to speak, or support minority groups did not help equality but rather simply drove a wedge between the people. I implore you to try to look at these issues from an outside perspective rather then the media induced brainwashed minds we have all been programmed to have.

Comment: ......end quote

Comment: My answer is correct. The reason is that **in the end,** the steps drove a wedge in people. If it had meant **some** steps, it would have been too vague, and wouldn't necessarily mean that it ended up driving a wedge between people.

Comment: In that context Tk may be right that what the speaker *wants* to believe is true is that all "methods" are counter-productive (or at least he wants his reader to believe that).  (Even a blind person knows that "Equality for the most part has been achieved for quite some time" is not true.)  He's intentionally using ambiguous language in an attempt to support his argument.

Comment: @HotLicks I sort of agree, since this was a debate. Chances are, the writer of this wants change in the way we take steps towards equality.